# How can I INSERT rows into a new table and update the primary key of the transported items?

Tags: sql, mysql

The new table has an auto-increment that I want to use for the data that I'm transferring.

Here is the query I want to run.

```
INSERT INTO `xyz_1mydata` SELECT * FROM `xyz_1production`  WHERE `xyz_1production.Id`  > '12000';
```

I don't want to replace the existing items in #_1mydata.

Comment: explain what does existing items in #_1mydata means? do you want to say that you don't want to insert a record from production into mydata if there's a matching id already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all the fields you want to transfer in your query. In this case, every field except the Id field. That way the rows inserted into xyz_1mydata will get newly generated IDs.

```
INSERT INTO xyz_1mydata (field1, field2, ...)
    SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM xyz_1production...
```

Comment: Thanks Matti, sounds very straightforward.